# how to create a table with input values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here i am getting values in fancybox when i click save buttion that values should be show it in table in my form.
here is the getting values code..

```
$(".add-lession").click( function() {
  if($('#ShowDay').val() != ''){
  var ShowDay=$("#ShowDay").val();
}else{
  alert('Please select day');
  return false;
}
  var Date=$("#Date").val();
  var StartTime=$("#StartTime").val();
  var EndTime=$("#EndTime").val();
  var Lession = $("#Lession").val();
  var Description = $("#Description").val();
});
```

thanks for ur help..

Comment: What do you mean `show it in table in my form`? Where is the table and the form?

Comment: Hi xdazz, i have a simple form with add buttion when i click add buttion we get a fancybox with fields after selecting the values and click save buttion i should get a table after the addbuttion in the form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = new Array(ShowDay,Date,StartTime,EndTime,Lesson,Description);

var tableElement = jQuery("<table />");
var trElement = jQuery("<tr/>");
var len = arr.length;
var tdElement;

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    tdElement = jQuery("<td/>",{text:arr[i]});
    trElement.append(tdElement);
}

tableElement.append(trElement);

$(".add-lession").parent().append(tableElement);
```

Comment: Hi Aditya,thanks for ur code and where should i write this code i mean $(".add-lession").click( function() { } ?

Comment: There are many ways and places, like

1) Put this between, `var Description = $("#Description").val();` and `});`
OR 2)
Create a new function, put this code in that function and then call that function at the same place as I mentioned in point 1.

Comment: @kiran what happened exactly?